# Uniform convergence on $[0,1]$ of $f_{n}(x)=x^{n}-3x^{n+2}+2x^{n+3}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I have sequence:
$f_{n}(x)=x^{n}-3x^{n+2}+2x^{n+3},x\in [0,1]$

Need to check uniform convergence

My steps:

1. Find $f(x)$

   $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}{ f_n(x)} = f(x) = 0$
2. $f_n(x)$ converge uniformly to the function f(x) if

   $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}{\sup|f_n(x)-f(x)|}=0$

   $g(x)=f_n(x)-f(x) = x^{n}-3x^{n+2}+2x^{n+3}$

I tried to find the extremum, but it's too difficult.
Is there another way of finding the supremum of $|g(x)|$?

Comment: $$f_{n}(x)=x^{n}-3x^{n+2}+2x^{n+3}$$

$$f'_{n}(x)=nx^{n-1}-3(n+2)x^{n+1}+2(n+3)x^{n+2} =x^{n-1}(n- 3(n+2)x^{2} +2(n+3)x^{3})$$ then find the extrema of the oplynomial of degree three in the bracket

Comment: $\lim{f_n(1)}=1-3*1+2*1=0$, for $x\in[0,1) \lim{f_n(x)=0}$ too, so f(x)$ converges pointwise.

Comment: It's $(x-1)*(2n+6)x^2-nx-n$ and $D = n^2+4*n*(2n+6)=9n^2+24n$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From $f_n(x)=2x^{n+3}-3x^{n+2}+x^n$, it's straightforward to obtain

$$f_n'(x)=2(n+3)x^{n+2}-3(n+2)x^{n+1}+nx^{n-1}=x^{n-1}(x-1)Q_n(x)$$

where $Q_n(x)=2(n+3)x^2+nx-n$. Since $Q_n(0)=-n\lt0$ and $Q_n({1\over2})={n+3\over2}+{n\over2}-n={3\over2}\gt0$, we see that the supremum of $|f_n|$ occurs at a value of $x$ between $0$ and $1\over2$. But for $0\lt x\lt{1\over2}$ we have

$$|f_n(x)|=x^{n-1}(x-1)^2(2x+1)\le2x^{n-1}\le{2\over2^{n-1}}={1\over2^{n-2}}$$

and thus $|f_n(x)|\le1/2^{n-2}$ for all $x\in[0,1]$.

Answer (score 2):

$f_n(x) = x^n (1-x)^2(1+2x)$ leads to $|f_n(x)|\leq 3x^n(1-x)^2$. On the other hand, over the interval $[0,1]$ the non-negative function $x^n(1-x)^2$ attains its maximum at $x=\frac{n}{2+n}$, and
$$\left(\frac{n}{n+2}\right)^n\cdot \left(\frac{2}{n+2}\right)^2\leq\frac{4}{(n+1)^2}, $$
thus $|f_n(x)|\leq\frac{12}{(n+1)^2}$ implies that the convergence towards zero is uniform.

Comment: I think you have a typo somewhere, because $x^{n+3}$ is missing

Comment: @Shashi: you are right, now fixed. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $ f_n(x) = x^n (1 - 3 x^2 + 2 x^3)$.  Given $\epsilon > 0$, take $\delta>0$ so $|1 - 3 x^2 + 2 x^3 |< \epsilon$ for $1-\delta \le x \le 1$, and take $N$ such that $|f_n(x)| \le \epsilon$ when $n \ge N$ and $0 \le x \le 1 - \delta$.